# Ручное обновление фильтра или динамический фильтр, как в Angular Translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Вот код на plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/e7OKHQWo0LpvMN8lVHpO?p=preview)

или тут:

```js
"use strict";
angular
  .module("exampleApp", [])
  .factory('currency', currencyFactory)
  .factory("User", userFactory)
  .filter("currency", currencyFilter)
  .controller("BaseCtrl", BaseCtrl);

function currencyFactory() {
  var ticker;
  const currency = {};

  currency.getTicker = function() {
    ticker = {
        "USD": {
          "buy": 1,
          "sell": 1,
          "symbol": "$",
          "decimalPlaces": 3,
          "name": "U.S. Dollar",
          "code": "USD"
        },
        "EUR": {
          "buy": 0.885,
          "sell": 0.885,
          "symbol": "€",
          "decimalPlaces": 3,
          "name": "Euro",
          "code": "EUR"
        }
      }
      // FakeRest
    return ticker;
  }
  currency.convertToUsd = function(amount, currency) {
    if (amount == 0) return 0;
    let cur = ticker[currency];
    if (amount == null || currency == null || !cur) return null;
    return (amount / cur.sell)
  };

  currency.convertFromUsd = function(amount, currency) {
    if (amount == 0) return 0;

    let cur = ticker[currency];
    if (amount == null || currency == null || !cur) return null;
    return (amount * cur.buy)
  };

  currency.formatForView = function(amount, currency) {
    let cur = ticker[currency];

    if (!cur) return null;

    return cur.symbol + amount.toFixed(cur.decimalPlaces);
  };
  currency.getList = function() {
    var array = [];
    console.log(ticker);
    angular.forEach(ticker, function(value) {
      array.push({
        code: value.code,
        name: value.name
      });
    });
    return array;
  };
  currency.getTicker();
  return currency;
}

function userFactory() {
  const user = {
    settings: {
      currency: "USD"
    }
  }
  user.change = function(to) {
    user.settings.currency = to;
  }
  return user;
}

currencyFilter.$inject = ["currency", "User"];

function currencyFilter(currencyFactory, User) {

  return function(amount, display = true, currency = User.settings.currency) {
    let converted = currencyFactory.convertFromUsd(amount, currency);
    return display ? currencyFactory.formatForView(converted, currency) : converted;
  }
}

function BaseCtrl($scope, User, currency) {
  $scope.currencies = currency.getList();
  $scope.current = User.settings.currency;
  $scope.change = function(to) {
    User.settings.currency = to;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="BaseCtrl">
  <h1>{{ 100.75 | currency }}</h1>
  <select ng-model="current">
    <option ng-repeat="currency in currencies" value="{{ currency.code }}">{{ currency.name }}</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы значение фильтра обновлялось при изменении `User.settings.currency`? Иными словами при изменении валюты?

**UPD:** Если приписать параметры к фильтру, несомненно будет работать. Но как добавить динамичности прямо из фильтра, как например в Angular Translate, где я могу написать `{{ "key" | translate }}` и при смене языка значение будет меняться само?

Comment: для селекта лучше использовать `ng-options` вместо `ng-repeat`

Comment: ну и директива нигде не используется, судя по всему вместо `directive` вы хотели `filter`

Comment: @Grundy, верно, я перепутал.

Comment: так надо объявить как фильтр, а не как директива, я выше в комментарии указал что на что :)

Comment: @Grundy, обновил вопрос, посмотрите, не работает все равно :(

Comment: похоже тут проблема совсем в другом :-) так как используется константное значение при фильтре, оно не меняется и следовательно нет оснований полагать, что изменится и значение фильтра. То есть фильтр просто не вызывается

Comment: Я вас не совсем понял. Констаны объявлены лишь две - в `User` и `currencyFactory`

Comment: _{{ 100.75 | currency }}_ - здесь 100.75 - константа

Comment: Я возможно туп, но что с ней сделать нужно? Перенести в контроллер? Если так, то не помогает. Сама сумма не меняется, меняется лишь **валюта**, тоесть доллары и евро. Попробуйте в планкере изменить значение `userFactory->user->settings` на EUR и поймете, чего я хочу.

Comment: Добавил ответ, с примером

Comment: Немного не то, что я хотел. А хотел я добавить динамичности не приписывая параметров в фильтр, как, например, в Angular Translate. Я могу просто написать `{{ "key" | translate }}` и при смене языка значение менятся само без параметров

Comment: обновил ответ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что в месте которое выводит конечное значение ничего не меняется

```
<h1>{{ 100.75 | currency }}</h1>
```

В данном случае фильтр вызывается всегда с одним и тем же параметром, и соответственно возвращает одно и то же значение.

Чтобы добавить динамичности, нужно передавать в фильтр параметр валюты в которую переводить:

```
100.75 | currency:current
```

Таким образом при изменении `current` будут произведены изменения везде где она используется.

Пример:

```js
"use strict";
angular
  .module("exampleApp", [])
  .factory('currency', currencyFactory)
  .factory("User", userFactory)
  .filter("currency", currencyFilter)
  .controller("BaseCtrl", BaseCtrl);

function currencyFactory() {
  var ticker;
  const currency = {};

  currency.getTicker = function() {
    ticker = {
        "USD": {
          "buy": 1,
          "sell": 1,
          "symbol": "$",
          "decimalPlaces": 3,
          "name": "U.S. Dollar",
          "code": "USD"
        },
        "EUR": {
          "buy": 0.885,
          "sell": 0.885,
          "symbol": "€",
          "decimalPlaces": 3,
          "name": "Euro",
          "code": "EUR"
        }
      }
      // FakeRest
    return ticker;
  }
  currency.convertToUsd = function(amount, currency) {
    if (amount == 0) return 0;
    let cur = ticker[currency];
    if (amount == null || currency == null || !cur) return null;
    return (amount / cur.sell)
  };

  currency.convertFromUsd = function(amount, currency) {
    if (amount == 0) return 0;

    let cur = ticker[currency];
    if (amount == null || currency == null || !cur) return null;
    return (amount * cur.buy)
  };

  currency.formatForView = function(amount, currency) {
    let cur = ticker[currency];

    if (!cur) return null;

    return cur.symbol + amount.toFixed(cur.decimalPlaces);
  };
  currency.getList = function() {
    var array = [];
    console.log(ticker);
    angular.forEach(ticker, function(value) {
      array.push({
        code: value.code,
        name: value.name
      });
    });
    return array;
  };
  currency.getTicker();
  return currency;
}

function userFactory() {
  const user = {
    settings: {
      currency: "USD"
    }
  }
  user.change = function(to) {
    user.settings.currency = to;
  }
  return user;
}

currencyFilter.$inject = ["currency", "User"];

function currencyFilter(currencyFactory, User) {

  return function(amount, currency = User.settings.currency, display = true) {
    let converted = currencyFactory.convertFromUsd(amount, currency);
    return display ? currencyFactory.formatForView(converted, currency) : converted;
  }
}

function BaseCtrl($scope, User, currency) {
  $scope.currencies = currency.getList()
  $scope.current = User.settings.currency;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="BaseCtrl">
  <h1>{{ 100.75 | currency:current }}</h1>
  <select ng-model="current" ng-options="currency.code as currency.name for currency in currencies">
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

**Обновление:** в [справке по фильтрам](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) указывается, что функции используемые в качестве фильтров должны быть *чистыми*, что значит у них не должно быть состояния, и они должны быть идемпотентны, т.е. одному входному параметру соответствует *один* результат. Это позволяет ангуляру проводить небольшую оптимизацию вызывая фильтр *только* когда входные параметры изменились.

Но так как иногда нужно, чтобы фильтр хранил свое состояние в ангуляр добавлен флаг `$stateful` показывающий, что у фильтра есть состояние и необходимо вычислять его на каждой итерации digest-цикла.

Таким образом с использованием этого флага пример будет выглядеть так:

```js
"use strict";
angular
  .module("exampleApp", [])
  .factory('currency', currencyFactory)
  .factory("User", userFactory)
  .filter("currency", currencyFilter)
  .controller("BaseCtrl", BaseCtrl);

function currencyFactory() {
  var ticker;
  const currency = {};

  currency.getTicker = function() {
    ticker = {
        "USD": {
          "buy": 1,
          "sell": 1,
          "symbol": "$",
          "decimalPlaces": 3,
          "name": "U.S. Dollar",
          "code": "USD"
        },
        "EUR": {
          "buy": 0.885,
          "sell": 0.885,
          "symbol": "€",
          "decimalPlaces": 3,
          "name": "Euro",
          "code": "EUR"
        }
      }
      // FakeRest
    return ticker;
  }
  currency.convertToUsd = function(amount, currency) {
    if (amount == 0) return 0;
    let cur = ticker[currency];
    if (amount == null || currency == null || !cur) return null;
    return (amount / cur.sell)
  };

  currency.convertFromUsd = function(amount, currency) {
    if (amount == 0) return 0;

    let cur = ticker[currency];
    if (amount == null || currency == null || !cur) return null;
    return (amount * cur.buy)
  };

  currency.formatForView = function(amount, currency) {
    let cur = ticker[currency];

    if (!cur) return null;

    return cur.symbol + amount.toFixed(cur.decimalPlaces);
  };
  currency.getList = function() {
    var array = [];
    console.log(ticker);
    angular.forEach(ticker, function(value) {
      array.push({
        code: value.code,
        name: value.name
      });
    });
    return array;
  };
  currency.getTicker();
  return currency;
}

function userFactory() {
  const user = {
    settings: {
      currency: "USD"
    }
  }
  user.change = function(to) {
    user.settings.currency = to;
  }
  return user;
}

currencyFilter.$inject = ["currency", "User"];

function currencyFilter(currencyFactory, User) {

  function filter(amount, display = true) {
    console.log('call filter', User.settings.currency);
    let converted = currencyFactory.convertFromUsd(amount, User.settings.currency);
    return display ? currencyFactory.formatForView(converted, User.settings.currency) : converted;
  }
  filter.$stateful = true;
  return filter;
}

function BaseCtrl($scope, User, currency) {
  $scope.currencies = currency.getList();
  $scope.current = User.settings;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="BaseCtrl">
  <h1>{{ 100.75 | currency }}</h1>
  <select ng-model="current.currency" ng-options="currency.code as currency.name for currency in currencies">
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, чего я хотел.

Comment: @Андрей, обрати внимание, что при использовании этой функции фильтр будет будет вызываться как минимум дважды на **каждой** итерации digest-цикла, поэтому лучше не использовать там сложных вычислений.